# Creating MP3 on Specific frequency

Tags: audio, mp3, html5-audio

Hello i want to create an MP3 file in specific frequencies, that i want which includes higher frequencies (above the human range 22kHz). 
I have tried HTML5 but it couldn't record Thanks

Comment: Do you need to do it programmatically? And what exactly should the mp3 contain? Just waveforms at a specific frequency, or some music with high-frequency sounds involved?
Also, _how_ have you tried with HTML5? Some context might help us help you :)

Comment: you need record using sample rate above of 44100hz, are you recording using microphone ? if yes your microphone input response need be able to track frequencies above 22Khz (Your microphone need to be incredibly good)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum frequency available is limited by the sample rate - lookup the notion of nyquist frequency - so web audio API can handle a max sample rate of 96kHz so its maximum frequency would be half that which is well above the human range.

What would be the source of the sound ? synthesized or recorded from microphone ?
Web Audio API supports both techniques - what platform do you need ? web / laptop ... ?
what language ?   mp3 is related to a compression codec - uncompressed audio data is called PCM (pulse code modulation) which you can save as a WAV format more directly.

To synthesize a frequency it can be as simple as saving into a buffer the points on a sin curve - here is some pseudo code

```
var max_samples = 100;
var num_cycles = 8; // influences frequency
var curr_theta = 0.0;
var incr_theta = 2 * Math.PI / (max_samples * num_cycles); // 2 * PI is one Hz

for (var curr_sample = 0; curr_sample < max_samples; curr_sample++) {

   audio_buffer[curr_sample] = Math.sin(curr_theta); // store current sample
   curr_theta += incr_theta;
}
```

You then save this audio_buffer into your output file - separate from the important topic of sample rate is the notion of bit depth - this is the resolution used to store each sample - typical audio uses 16 bits as its bit depth per sample - if you store each entry in the above audio_buffer as 16 bits then you will need to chop it into 8 bit bytes during the file saving step (watch out for your endian-ness)

Comment: The sample rate of the Web Audio API is dependent on the context, which is dependent on the hardware, configuration, and browser.  You cannot set the sample rate, and I have yet to see a device/browser combination that will do 96kHz.  (Not that it can't happen...)